# Rank one sheaves and ideal sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For a coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ on a smooth irreducible projective variety $X/k$, it makes sense to define the rank $\textrm{rk }\mathcal F$ as the rank of the vector bundle $\mathcal F|_U$, where $U$ is the open subset of $X$ where $\mathcal F$ is locally free.

Ideal sheaves $\mathscr I\subset\mathcal O_X$ are coherent of rank one.

> *Question*. Is there a known criterion saying when a coherent subsheaf $\mathcal
> F\subset \mathcal O_X$ of rank one is an ideal sheaf?

Thanks for any suggestion, or reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any subsheaf  of $\mathcal O_X$-modules $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal O_X$ on a scheme (or even on a ringed space) is an ideal sheaf.
All the other adjectives  (rank-one, coherent, smooth, projective, irreducible,...) are irrelevant.

Also, you shouldn't believe that  ideal sheaves must  be of rank one or quasi- coherent :
On the spectrum $X=\text {Spec} R$ of a discrete valuation ring $R$, consider the ideal sheaf $\mathcal I$ with  global sections $\Gamma(X,\mathcal I)=R$ and  whose sections over the (open!) generic point  are given by  $\Gamma(\{\eta\},\mathcal I)=0$.
The sheaf $\mathcal I$ is an ideal sheaf which is not quasi-coherent and which is of rank zero .

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, your answers are always illuminating. May I just ask you "how much" your example is pathological? For instance: can we have rank $0$ ideal sheaves $I\subset O_X$ for $X$ a projective variety over a field $k=\overline k$? let us say one looks at ideals of curves in $X$, or curves and points...? For sure, ideals of zero-dimensional subschemes are rank-one!

Comment: Dear @Brenin: yes, my example *is* pathological and non-geometric: I should have emphasized this  in my answer. In the geometric context of varieties or schemes over a field, ideal sheaves  tend  however  to be coherent and rank one, unless one  deliberately considers nasty examples. Nice and fairly typical rank one examples are given by the ideal sheaves corresponding to closed subvarieties.